# Understanding the use of brackets in the all function in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

I'm trying to wrap my head around the conventions and rules of programming in Haskell. One thing that I find confusing or difficult to understand is the use of brackets (). Can anyone explain to me what it does in the case of the all function?

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all p xs = and [ p x | x <- xs ]
```

As I understand it, the type of a function shows the type constraints, inputs and outputs. Wouldn't having

```
all :: [a] -> Bool
```

Be enough?

Comment: `all` takes two arguments: a predicate function (i.e. a boolean test for the elements) and a list.

Comment: @duplode Ohh I see! Thank you

Comment: @Elmex80s `and` has the signature `[Bool] -> Bool`

Answer (score 5):

#### What parentheses do here

Parentheses in Haskell serve a purpose that is very similar to most other programming languages: changing precedence of operations and/or grouping terms.

In your case, the fact that `(a -> Bool)` is wrapped in parentheses shows that the type of the function's first parameter is `a -> Bool`. If there was no parentheses (i.e. if the signature was `all :: a -> Bool -> [a] -> Bool`), then the meaning would be that the type of the function's first parameter is `a`, and the type of the function's second parameter is `Bool`.

#### Wouldn't it be enough to have `all :: [a] -> Bool`?

If that was the signature, then the question would be: what does such function mean? Does it return `True` when the list is not empty? Or when it's empty? Or when it contains precisely 42 elements? A bad name for a function. Should have named it `has42Elements` instead of `all`.

On the other hand, if the function takes the first parameter of type `a -> Bool` (that is, a function that takes an `a` and returns a `Bool`), then the meaning of `all` would be "*check if this function is `True` for all elements in this list*".